# How to get recommendation contents like Android TV launcher?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to develop an android tv launcher, but I don't know how to get recommendation contents from other apps?
[like this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6hH4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations.html) regarding *Recommending TV Content*. This [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) teaches you how to create recommendations and provide them to the Android framework so users can easily discover and enjoy your app content. It also demonstrates how to use the Leanback Support library which enables you to easily develop beautiful Android TV apps with a user-friendly UI that complies with the UX guidelines of Android TV.

Once your recommendation service starts running, it must create recommendations and pass them to the Android framework. The framework receives the recommendations as [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) objects that use a specific template and are marked with a specific category.